# JavaScript: Pass JSON obj out from parse function?

Tags: json, function, global-variables, pass-by-value

I'm trying to pass an object out of a function. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// finds the head element; creates a script with passed url; appends it to the head
function loadJSON(url) {
  var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
  var newScript = document.createElement('script');
      newScript.type = 'text/javascript'; // isn't this 'application/json' really?
      newScript.src = url;
  headID.appendChild(newScript);
}

function parseJSON(o) {
  if (content == null) {
    document.write("<p>parseJSON(): JSON failed.</p>");
    return false;
  }

  isDST = "<strong>not</strong> ";
  if ( o.rawOffset == o.dstOffset ) {
    isDST = "";
  }
  document.getElementById("geonames").innerHTML = "<p>The time now is " + o.time + " in " + o.countryName +".</p>";
}

var lat = "47.01"; var long = "10.2"; // test data for austria
var jsonUrl = " {{URL}} ";
loadJSON(jsonUrl);
</script>
```

What I want to do is instead of using the object o inside the parseJSON function I want to pass the object out so that after the loadJSON() call I can do things with the object. I find it's not "neat" having the innerHTML calls inside the parse function.

I've tried lots of iterations of, eg declaring "var jsonOutput" at start of script and then making "jsonOutput =  o" but that just leaves jsonOutput undefined. If I try to return jsonOutput then I don't know where it's being returned to, I can't use it anyway.

Do I need to make a global variable? I've tried a simple "global jsonOutput" declaration but it doesn't seem to be modified inside the function.

Am stuck, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it seems that you are trying to load the JSON data using the `<script>` tag.

You could also load the JSON data via an [XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/xmlhttpreq.html) and then turn it into an object via:

```
var dataObject = eval('(' + myJSONData + ')');
```

And if you can't verify how secure the data is, you can use the [official JSON JavaScript parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (see [here](http://json.org/js) for more information) to validate the data before executing it.

Steve

Comment: I was trying to avoid using XMLHttpRequest as I gather it's heavier on network transactions? Thanks for the advice though, I'm confident about the source so am not using json2.js this time.

Comment: I'm not sure why an XMLHttpRequest would be any heavier than directly loading the file into the HTML page... I think it's a fairly common practice to use an XMLHttpRequest whenever you need to load XML/JSON data in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your scenario completely, but have you tried to return a whole object as opposed to returning just a boolean or json?

```
function parseJSON(o)
{
   // Your code here
   var result = new Object();
   result.IsSuccess = true; // or false
   result.JSON = someData; // your json output
   return result;
}

function loadJSON()
{
   // Your code here
   var jsonParseResult = ParseJSON(o);
   if (jsonParseResult.IsSuccess)
   {
       // More code here involving jsonParseResult.JSON
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the parseJSON is the callback, so it has the JSON code received from offsite as object "o", that's the data I want to expose outside the function. I tried "var jsonOutput = {};" (in and out of the function) and then setting "jsonOutput = o; return jsonOutput" but that doesn't seem to do it.